# Making href link work with Yahoo Pipes regex

Tags: regex, hyperlink, rss, href, yahoo-pipes

I am using Yahoo Pipes for some time now, but I have now trouble with the regex function.

In particular, I try to get the document  and link for "1. Template notes and cash report Master Issuer version (xls)" from "http://www.dutchsecuritisation.nl/investor-reporting".

I want to have the latest version of the document on my site and included the rss feed: "http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.edit?_id=9a05b11c5ff1a481722acf867a2f96b7" there. In contrast to other pipes that I have made, YP returns "Invalid Action", when I click on the link of the document Master Issuer version (or the other documents).

If I look at the pipe results, I see that it separates the href in a special box ([see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHvuu.png)), therefore I have included a regex expression: item.link rename: (?i).*?href="([^"]*).* with $1 (s box checked)-see picture. I found this code in the question: "Regular expression on Yahoo! pipes".

Can you help me with getting the regex in such a way that the feed retrieves a link that works?

Comment: What a crazy stuff, Yahoo pipes!

Comment: Hi Lorenz, thanks for your comment and vote; what do you mean with "crazy stuff"?! thanks, kr, Pippijn

Comment: I looked at the picture. It looks crazy for the non-initiated mind. Like a lump of wool left with a cat. Or like the visual representation of 'spaghetti code'. Or... I'm joking, but I'm happy to have to deal only with written code, it looks quite less impressive.